# Java, why do my graphics draw out of the the frame/range they should be in?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

So, I am making a program that currently draws filled circles of a random size (between 6-9 inclusive) randomly on a JFrame of size 1024x768. The problem I am having, is that even after I coded in a rule that should ensure that all the circles fall within the 1024x768 JFrame, the circles fall outside of the desired boundaries. Below is the code segment that should generate the correct location for each circle:

```
private static KillZoneLocation generateLocation(){
    int genX,genY;
    int xmax = 1024 - generatedGraphic.getRadius();
    int ymax = 768 - generatedGraphic.getRadius();
    KillZoneLocation location = new KillZoneLocation();
    do{
        genX = generatedGraphic.getRadius() + (int)(Math.random()*xmax);
        genY = generatedGraphic.getRadius() +(int)(Math.random()*ymax);
        location.setXcoord(genX);
        location.setYcoord(genY);
        generatedLocation = location;
    }while(isOverlaping(location));

    return location;
}
```

generatedGraphic is a global variable from the class containing the method above and returns a number between 6 and 9 inclusive

generatedGraphic.getRadius() returns a random number from this algorithm int radius = 7 + (int)(Math.random()*9); The number has been generated prior by a different method. This method is just a getter. The radius number is not generated every time this method is called.

isOverlaping(locations) just checks to make sure the circle does not overlap another circle that is already placed on the JFrame.

location.set... Those are just setter methods.

I'm thinking this is just a silly logic error, but I still can't seem to figure out why the circles are printing outside of the frame.

I am purposely avoiding posting anymore code because it will confuse you since the program has a much larger scope then I have described and there are a dozen files all interwinded. I debugged this code and realized numbers being returned by: 
        genX = generatedGraphic.getRadius() + (int)(Math.random()*xmax);
        genY = generatedGraphic.getRadius() +(int)(Math.random()*ymax);

Return numbers out of range.

Draw class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KillZoneGUI extends JFrame{

    public KillZoneGUI(){
        setSize(1024,768);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        GenerateKillZone.setup(1024,768);
        new KillZoneGUI();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(Robot r: KillZone.getRobots()){
            g.setColor(r.getGraphic().getColor());
            g.fillOval(
                       r.getLocation().getXcoord(), 
                       r.getLocation().getYcoord(),
                       r.getGraphic().getRadius(),
                       r.getGraphic().getRadius()); 
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: We're definitely going to need to see the draw method as well.

Comment: Never draw directly in the JFrame. Draw in a JPanel or JComponent extended class's `paintComponent(...)` method, and get the dimensions of this drawing panel inside of this method so that there is no doubt as to the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should read

```
genX = (int)(Math.random()*xmax);
genY = (int)(Math.random()*ymax);
```

Remember that [Graphics2D.fillOval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) will use genX/genY for the top left corner, and the oval will extend by the value of getRadius().  You're subtracting the size of your radius, but then adding it back in twice!  Once in your genX/Y assignments, and once when you draw the oval.

Answer (score 0):

```
int xmax = 1024 - 2 * generatedGraphic.getRadius();
int ymax = 768 - 2 * generatedGraphic.getRadius();
```

As you are starting from generatedGraphic.getRadius(); and may only go to xmax/ymax.

And then use the answer of @JasonNichols, fillOval starting with (left, top) (0, 0) to width - diameter.

Comment: Yes, this is also something I should have done. I didn't realize the it drew from the top left corner.

Comment: Yes fillOval at 0, 2*radius; I overlooked it too; +1 for Jason.